# Using Gradle and AspectJ with Android product flavors that have their own source

Tags: android, gradle, aop, aspectj

I have searched a lot, but haven't seen an answer for this.  I have source that's in different flavors.  Something like:

```
App/src/flavorA/MyFlavor.java
App/src/flavorB/MyFlavor.java
App/src/flavorC/MyFlavor.java
```

And it works great, until I need to run my AOP step.  I found it couldn't complete because it was unable to find this class, which is referenced from source in App/src/main/.

This doesn't find the MyFlavor class:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.javaCompile.doLast {
        def androidSdk = android.adbExe.parent + "/../platforms/" + project.ext.android_version + "/android.jar"
        def iajcClasspath = configurations.compile.asPath + ";" + androidSdk

        // This add's project jars as well as support jars.
        project.ext.tree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/exploded-aar", include: '**/*.jar')
        project.ext.tree.each { jarFile ->
            iajcClasspath += ":" + jarFile
        }

        ant.taskdef(resource: "org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties",
                classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(
                source: "1.6",
                target: "1.6",
                destDir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${variant.dirName}",
                fork: "true",
                maxmem: "512m",
                aspectPath: configurations.aspects.asPath,
                inpath: configurations.ajInpath.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter: "**/.svn/*,**/*.java",
                classpath: iajcClasspath
        ) {
            sourceroots {
                android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
                    pathelement(location: it.absolutePath)
                }

                pathelement(location: "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/r/${variant.dirName}")
                pathelement(location: "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/buildConfig/${variant.dirName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get it working if I add in something like:

```
pathelement(location: "$`enter code here`{project.buildDir}/../src/flavorA/java")
```

But that's if I only want to build flavorA.  Is there a better way of setting things up so that when the IAJC task runs, it can find the source that it needs for the particular variant that it's building?  If I assembleFlavorARelease, my variant name is going to be something like flavorARelease and I can get the build type of "release" by doing variant.buildType.name but that's not going to help me.  I need to point it to the source for the flavor I'm building.

I took the variant.name and subtracted the build type name off of it to be left with the "flavorA" part:

```
pathelement(location: "${project.buildDir}/../src/${variant.name.substring(0, variant.name.length() - variant.buildType.name.length())}/java")
```

Still seems wonky.  What if I want to assembleRelease and build all flavors?  There's got to be a better way of approaching this which I'm not seeing.

Comment: It seems as though the sourceroots specified only look at android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { ... } and add those as pathelements.  The problem is I have code in android.sourceSets.flavorA, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the available flavors for your particular variant using:

    `def currentFlavor;
    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        flavorToChoose = flavor
    }`

From here you can grab onto the flavor you want from the list and then add a path element similar to the "main" source set like:

`android.sourceSets."${flavorToChoose}".java.srcDirs.each {
        pathelement(location: it.absolutePath)
    }`

Make sure to stick this block in your sourceroots section.

Comment: Still feels dirty and fragile.  Don't get me wrong, it can work.  If you can write or use a plugin like this:  [GradleAndroidAspectJPlugin](https://github.com/leolin310148/GradleAndroidAspectJPlugin)  I think you can keep your Gradle simpler, but you're dependent on something else.